# why you should follow it?

Tags: logic

We learned expression of deduce, i.e. =>.

But now I dont have capable reason for I agree I represent True if assumption is False.

Anybady there having to explain reason for its deduce?

Best regards,

Comment: Do you mean to ask why $P \implies Q$ is true when $P$ is false?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @quickybrown Then you should have written that - what you've written right now isn't clear at all.

Comment: In my impression, we are going to merge $\urcorner P \vee Q \ and \ P =>Q$. 
Is this a correct?

Comment: @quickybrown Yes, in classical logic, $p\to q$ and $\lnot p\lor q$ mean the same thing.

Comment: The basic reason is that $\Rightarrow$ is the "if ..., then ..." connective and does not mean "to deduce".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table that should help

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline
P & Q & P\Rightarrow Q \\ \hline
T   & T   & T                \\ \hline
T   & F   & F                \\ \hline
F   & T   & T                \\ \hline
F   & F   & T                \\ \hline
\end{array}

For the first row, $P$ and $Q$ are both assumed true thus $P \Rightarrow Q$ will be true. For the second row, $P$ is true and $Q$ is false thus $P\Rightarrow Q$ will say okay well what is the result of the ending statement? false since $Q$ is the result of the ending statement in $P\Rightarrow Q$. Same logic in reverse applied to the third row. Latly, $P$ and $Q$ are now both false, thus $P\Rightarrow Q$ will return true since both statements both have the same assumed false value. I hope that is clear.

As an extension to this exercise try this one to solidify your understanding:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline
P & Q & Q\Rightarrow P \\ \hline
T   & T   &                 \\ \hline
T   & F   &                 \\ \hline
F   & T   &                 \\ \hline
F   & F   &                 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

One rather intuitive understanding is that the equivalence $\Leftrightarrow$ can be understood as a conjunction of $\Leftarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$ thus $F\Rightarrow X$ has to be true independent of whether $X$ stands for true or false. 
As long as the implication does not get violated by a clear example that falsifies it ($T\Rightarrow F$) it is considered to be true.

Comment: But if you have  given intuitve function pretend F is T and T is F, can you distinguish between F and T. I don't understand.